# Spring elasticsearch Exception when calling IndexOperations.createWithMapping on startup?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elastic-stack, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have the following code that is being created on startup:

```
@EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
  public void createIndexMappingsOnStartup() {
    final IndexOperations indexOperations = this.elasticsearchOperations.indexOps(Person.class);
    indexOperations.createWithMapping();
}
```

I receive the following exception:

```
Elasticsearch exception [type=resource_already_exists_exception, reason=index [person/71QDnf0oSqW9q32hDRm8DQQ] already exists]",
```

But if I use the following code, I receive no error:

```
final IndexOperations indexOperations = this.elasticsearchOperations.indexOps(Person.class);
indexOperations.putMapping();
```

Can somebody tell me what's going on here? I need to create the field mapping on startup.

Answer (score 0):

Well the error clearly states that you want to create an index that already exists, you cannot create an index multiple times in Elasticsearch.

Please note, that when you re-start the application, you cannot write the mapping again to the index, mappings cannot be updated.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But why is it I got no error when I use the putMapping() method?

Comment: I don't know. Your code does not show when the index is created or by what.